# RegEx Scope of Alternation

Tags: regex

What is the scope of the alternation operator `|`? In some cases, it appears that everything to the left of `|` is one alternative and everything to the right of the `|` is the second alternative. Why are the alternatives not limited to the capture groups or tokens immediately preceding and following the `|`?

I am testing with [RegExr](http://regexr.com/), but I will be running the regular expressions in Java.

I have two short regular expressions:

```
(\d{3})\W+(SSN)
```

(Matches in bold.)

SSNx **123 SSN**

```
(SSN)\W+(\d{3})
```

(Matches in bold.)

**SSN 123** SSN

If I combine the regular expressions like this:

```
(\d{3})\W+(SSN)|(SSN)\W+(\d{3})
```

The regular expression matches (in bold)

**SSN 123** SSN

SSNx **123 SSN**

Why was it unnecessary for me to add parentheses like this?

```
((\d{3})\W+(SSN))|((SSN)\W+(\d{3}))
```

I expected the alternation operation to alternate only between the surrounding capture groups, e.g. "SSN" OR "SSN". If that were the case, then the results would look like this:

```
((\d{3})\W+(SSN)\W+(\d{3}))
```

No matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a question of scope, it's a question of precedence, and [alternation has the lowest precedence of all operators.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

> The alternation operator has the lowest precedence of all regex operators. That is, it tells the regex engine to match either everything to the left of the vertical bar, or everything to the right of the vertical bar. If you want to limit the reach of the alternation, you need to use parentheses for grouping.

You said that you *"expected the alternation operation to alternate only between the surrounding capture groups."* But, because alternation has the lowest precedence, it matches either everything to the left or everything to the right.