# Matching a string regardless of whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

I'm creating a regular expression that's meant to match license plate numbers in two formats: either {a number from 1 to 9}-{5 uppercase letters or numbers}, or {a 2-digit number}-{4 uppercase letters or numbers}.

I'm using the following regex pattern: `^\s*[1-9]-[A-Z1-9]{5}|[1-9][0-9]-[A-Z1-9]{4}\s*$`. Some examples of what it matches are: `45-Y21A`, `3-78UTW`, and `67-AASE`.

My current issue is that the regular expression will not match license plate numbers with trailing whitespaces, for example, `5-37D8F`  . I thought `\s*` would take care of that, but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

The regular expression matches leading whitespaces just fine, so I am lost as to why it has trouble with trailing spaces.

Comment: Wrap the two branches inside a group: [`^\s*(?:...|...)\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/U0vS2T/1).

Comment: This is quite a common problem: `^\s*` and `\s*$` each apply to a single branch. There is a duplicate target somewhere, but it's truly hard to find.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx Scope of Alternation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339422/regex-scope-of-alternation)

Comment: @InSync I did a search for `[regex] scope alternation` and the first result seemed best.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want to match license plate numbers with their leading and trailing whitespaces (if I understood the task correctly) instead of the license plate numbers themselves, but it seems your pattern doesn't match either the leading spaces or the trailing spaces, at least in most cases.

The following pattern, however, appears to do the job:

```
^\s*(?:\d-[A-Z1-9]{5}|\d{2}-[A-Z1-9]{4})\s*$
```

as shown in the trials below:

```py
import re

your_pattern = r"^\s*[1-9][-][A-Z1-9]{5}|([1-9][0-9])[-][A-Z1-9]{4}\s*$"
my_pattern = r"^\s*(?:\d-[A-Z1-9]{5}|\d{2}-[A-Z1-9]{4})\s*$"

license_plate_numbers = [
    "45-Y21A",
    "3-78UTW",
    "  67-AASE",
    "5-37D8F",
    "5-37D8F   ",
    " 5-37D8F ",
]

for license_plate_number in license_plate_numbers:
    match1 = re.match(your_pattern, license_plate_number)
    match2 = re.match(my_pattern, license_plate_number)

    print(f"License plate number: '{license_plate_number}'")

    if match1:
        print(f"Your pattern matches: '{match1.group(0)}'")
    else:
        print("Your pattern does not match anything")

    if match2:
        print(f"My pattern matches: '{match2.group(0)}'")
    else:
        print("My pattern does not match anything")

    print()
```

Output:

```
License plate number: '45-Y21A'
Your pattern matches: '45-Y21A'
My pattern matches: '45-Y21A'

License plate number: '3-78UTW'
Your pattern matches: '3-78UTW'
My pattern matches: '3-78UTW'

License plate number: '  67-AASE'
Your pattern does not match anything
My pattern matches: '  67-AASE'

License plate number: '5-37D8F'
Your pattern matches: '5-37D8F'
My pattern matches: '5-37D8F'

License plate number: '5-37D8F   '
Your pattern matches: '5-37D8F'
My pattern matches: '5-37D8F   '

License plate number: ' 5-37D8F '
Your pattern matches: ' 5-37D8F'
My pattern matches: ' 5-37D8F '
```